# ExpressJS middleware with NextJS not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

As the title suggests I have a next.js app that is using ExpressJS as a custom server. I set up a simple middleware to do some logging but it is not being called at all.

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.use(helmet());
  server.use(bodyParser.json());

  // >>> this is not being called <<<
  server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("LOGGED");
  });

  server.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const indexPage = "/";
    app.render(req, res, indexPage);
  });
  server.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    const aboutPage = "/about";
    app.render(req, res, aboutPage);
  });
  server.post("/search", [
    checkSpotifyToken,
    async (req, res) => {
      const { selectedMovie } = req.body;
      try {
        const playlistId = await buildPlaylist(selectedMovie);
        res.json({ success: true, playlistId });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({ success: false });
      }
    }
  ]);
  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });
  server.listen(3001, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I was expecting to see `LOGGED` printed out, and it is not.

Comment: But your routes such as `/about` are rendering as expected?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: That's very odd. What I would expect from what you have here is that you would see the log, but you wouldn't get to any of the routes, because you are not calling `next()` in your logging function. That's what I see when I run similar code locally. But, maybe it's worth trying adding a call to `next();` after your console.log

Comment: I call const server = express(); outside of the app.prepare() function, right after you establish const handle = app.getRequestHandler.

Comment: What is this `const app = next({ dev });`?  You appear to have both `app` and `server` and seem to be using them somewhat interchangeably, but  they aren't the same thing.

Comment: @jfriend00 that comes from the NextJS framework. https://github.com/zeit/next.js

Comment: I'm having the same problem!  Wondering if its an issue with how the dev environment is setup?

Comment: could you please remove `server.use(bodyParser.json());` cause I'm experiencing a similar issue.